# MongoDB Fragmentation affect the Performance in WiredTiger

Tags: mongodb, fragmentation, wiredtiger

Im using MongoDB 3.6 I have a huge number of fragmentation in my collections. 300+ GB on one collection. WiredTiger is the storage engine.

I know its bad for the OS and much wasted space. This affects the memory as well if we use MMAP engine. But I don't know how the fragmentation affects the WiredTiger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be less efficient to fetch data if you have a lot of space available for reuse. However, that space could be reused if you continue to insert or update documents in the collection.

If you've dropped a significant amount of data (which sounds like ~300GB in one of your collections) you can reclaim space by either:

- [re-syncing members of a replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/) (recommended if you want to reclaim space from all collections)
- [running the `compact` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/compact/) (important caveat: this will block all operations for the database the operation is running on)

For either approach I would use [rolling maintenance](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-maintence-on-replica-set-members/) to maintain availability.

A resync would be the most effective option. The `compact` command is riskier to run as a replica set member may become stale while running `compact` offline (and require resync); this operation may also not be able to free as much disk space as a resync and needs to be run per collection.